# qemu-kvm command not found

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu

I have installed kvm in my computer using:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
```

But when I try to run the command:

```
qemu-kvm -m 384 -cdrom guestos.iso -hda image.img -boot d
```

to boot an ISO image from cdrom, it gives the error stating "qemu-kvm command not found".
Have I missed on installing any required package? And if not, what is missing?

Answer (score 9):

Try `kvm -m 384 -cdrom guestos.iso -hda image.img -boot d`